# Put desired row id on top

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following PHP code with the query to retrieve the products from database:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE id_category = :id_category";
$query = $conn->prepare($sql);
$query->execute(array
(
    'id_category' => $id_category
));

while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    extract($row);
    echo $id_product; //1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 etc
}
```

What I need is to put the row of the product with id **5** on top, and I simply don't know how to do this. My attempts with `ORDER BY` all have failed.

Comment: I don't think that this is possible.

Comment: So the solution can't be done with sql? Using PHP so, but how?

Comment: @aynber Thanks, I was searching for some question according to it but found nothing.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM products WHERE id_category = :id_category order by id=5 desc` ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, with the `ORDER BY` clause be specific with the order returned so perhaps for your needs you can try:

```
select * from `products` where `id_category` = :id_category order by `id`=5 desc;
```

As an example of how this changes the ordering consider the following

```
mysql> select * from accounts;
+----+-----------+----------+----------+
| id | sponsorID | open     | close    |
+----+-----------+----------+----------+
|  1 |        23 | 6:00 AM  | 10:30 PM |
|  2 |        23 | 6:00 AM  | 8:30 PM  |
|  3 |        21 | 11:00 AM | 5:30 PM  |
|  4 |        23 | 7:00 AM  | 2:30 PM  |
|  5 |        24 | 9:00 AM  | 11:30 PM |
|  6 |        25 | 6:00 AM  | 9:30 PM  |
|  7 |        99 | 6:00 AM  | 9:30 PM  |
+----+-----------+----------+----------+


mysql> select * from accounts order by id=5 desc;
+----+-----------+----------+----------+
| id | sponsorID | open     | close    |
+----+-----------+----------+----------+
|  5 |        24 | 9:00 AM  | 11:30 PM |
|  1 |        23 | 6:00 AM  | 10:30 PM |
|  2 |        23 | 6:00 AM  | 8:30 PM  |
|  3 |        21 | 11:00 AM | 5:30 PM  |
|  4 |        23 | 7:00 AM  | 2:30 PM  |
|  6 |        25 | 6:00 AM  | 9:30 PM  |
|  7 |        99 | 6:00 AM  | 9:30 PM  |
+----+-----------+----------+----------+
```

You can specify more than one explicit term in the order by or mix the ordering of subsequent columns

```
mysql> select * from accounts order by id=5 desc, id desc;
+----+-----------+----------+----------+
| id | sponsorID | open     | close    |
+----+-----------+----------+----------+
|  5 |        24 | 9:00 AM  | 11:30 PM |
|  7 |        99 | 6:00 AM  | 9:30 PM  |
|  6 |        25 | 6:00 AM  | 9:30 PM  |
|  4 |        23 | 7:00 AM  | 2:30 PM  |
|  3 |        21 | 11:00 AM | 5:30 PM  |
|  2 |        23 | 6:00 AM  | 8:30 PM  |
|  1 |        23 | 6:00 AM  | 10:30 PM |
+----+-----------+----------+----------+
```

or

```
mysql> select * from accounts order by id=5 desc, id=1 desc, id desc;
+----+-----------+----------+----------+
| id | sponsorID | open     | close    |
+----+-----------+----------+----------+
|  5 |        24 | 9:00 AM  | 11:30 PM |
|  1 |        23 | 6:00 AM  | 10:30 PM |
|  7 |        99 | 6:00 AM  | 9:30 PM  |
|  6 |        25 | 6:00 AM  | 9:30 PM  |
|  4 |        23 | 7:00 AM  | 2:30 PM  |
|  3 |        21 | 11:00 AM | 5:30 PM  |
|  2 |        23 | 6:00 AM  | 8:30 PM  |
+----+-----------+----------+----------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a UNION of 2 queries to achieve this. Let me rewrite just the query here:

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE id_category = :id_category WHERE id=5
UNION
SELECT * FROM products WHERE id_category = :id_category WHERE id!=5
```

Answer (score 1):

I would populate a new array and use `array_unshift()`;

```
$rowHolder = array();
while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    if ($row['id_category'] !== 5) {
        $rowHolder[] = $row;
    } else {
        array_unshift($rowHolder, $row);
    }
}
```

$rowHolder now holds all the rows, with the row having id = 5 at the zero index.

Answer (score 1):

It's trivial in MySQL:

```
SELECT ...
...
ORDER BY (id_category = 5) DESC, id_category
```

This works by taking the result of `(id_category = 5)`, which is a boolean true/false, and casting it to an integer `0`/`1` and sorting them in DESC order. That places all of the `5` records at the TOP of the result set, then the remaining non-`5` records are sorted as usual in the second place `id_category` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$sql = "SELECT *,(id_category=5) as top FROM products WHERE id_category = :id_category ORDER BY top DESC";
$query = $conn->prepare($sql);
$query->execute(array
(
    'id_category' => $id_category
));
```